# How do I get the proper data format for creating a tilegram -- from MULTIPOLYGONS to POLYGONS

Tags: r, sf, leaflet-r, cartogram

I want to create a cartogram(specifically a tilegram like [this](https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/2016-election-forecast/#electoral-map)) using data from GADM and population figures as the subject variable.

Step 1: Get a json data file from GADM

```
germany_1 <- read_sf("gadm41_DEU_1.json")
```

This is what I have:

```
# germany_1$geometry

Geometry set for 16 features 
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 5.8663 ymin: 47.2708 xmax: 15.0418 ymax: 55.0565
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
First 5 geometries:
MULTIPOLYGON (((8.35 47.5706, 8.3284 47.5712, 8...
MULTIPOLYGON (((11.4101 47.4954, 11.408 47.4911...
MULTIPOLYGON (((13.5002 52.6138, 13.4968 52.605...
MULTIPOLYGON (((13.3222 51.4367, 13.3258 51.433...
MULTIPOLYGON (((8.675 53.1781, 8.6757 53.1752, ...
```

I transform the geometry values from MULTIPLOYGONS to POLYGONS using sf's st_cast:

```
germany_polygon <- st_cast(germany_1, "POLYGON")
```

This is what I get:

```
Geometry set for 114 features 
Geometry type: POLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 5.8663 ymin: 47.2708 xmax: 15.0418 ymax: 55.0565
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
First 5 geometries:
POLYGON ((8.35 47.5706, 8.3284 47.5712, 8.3221 ...
POLYGON ((8.6801 49.6187, 8.6801 49.6203, 8.684...
POLYGON ((8.6741 47.6979, 8.6765 47.6979, 8.673...
POLYGON ((11.4101 47.4954, 11.408 47.4911, 11.3...
POLYGON ((13.5002 52.6138, 13.4968 52.6051, 13....
```

When I expand on the `geometry`, I expect to get "list of length 58", for example but all observations have "list of length 1". As such, there are no values to generate the tilegrams.

Also, `dim(germany_polygon)` gives `[1] 114  12`, but I expected similar levels as `dim(germany_1)` output `[1] 16 12`.

The purpose of this effort is to create a tilegram like this one from GADM data. Any directions are welcome.

Comment: The geoJSON gives you MULTIPOLYGON because some of the features (rows) are made up of multiple rings. See `plot(germany_1$geometry[5])`. If you convert to POLYGON you split these into single features. Why did you think you needed to do that?

Comment: Are you trying to make exactly this: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Germany_population_states_hexagonal.svg

Comment: Yes, I want to make such an image linked from wikimedia. To your first question, I am assuming each of this single feature will be the hex/circle to be plot. After plotting `plot(germany_1$geometry[5]` I see what you mean by multiple rings. What should I do then? As a learner, I have tried reading multiple documentations around this issue but I do not know how to get that final image (like Wikipedia).

Comment: Have you found a package that creates these sorts of cartograms? What input does it expect?

Comment: Yes - this is the closest I found, TilegramsR: https://github.com/bhaskarvk/tilegramsR
For example, `class(sf_france_regions_population)` is `[1] "sf"         "data.frame"`

Getting that data object right is what I have trying up there. I have not found any documentation or specifications on the expected object.